# Windows sleeps while running a long C++ Visual Studio program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, visual-studio-debugging, sleep-mode

I am using Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 and I have a C++ project which runs over 15 minutes. But the problem is the windows gets into sleep while my is still debugging.

I know this is occured because the sleep wait time is exceeded while running the program (debugging), and I can easily stop this by either increasing sleep wait time or set the settings to "never" sleep in the Windows Control Pannel Power Settings.

But I want a programatical or Visual Studio based solution for this. I want my computer not to sleep in the midst of execution (debugging) of a program.

Comment: Call SetThreadExecutionState() periodically.

Comment: Refer http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/preventing-your-monitor-from-going-to-sleep-with-visual-studio-2012.htm

Comment: But I am just curious, why don't you simply change system settings and prevent sleep?

Comment: @user1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx

Comment: @user1 I'm afraid that the link u provided doesn't have the solution for C++

Comment: Yes, solution is in C#, I just want to let you know the idea. Take idea from there and implement it on your own. Stackoverflow is not a platform where you get ready-made solutions!

Comment: @user1 Preventing sleep via system settings is not a solution as I would be working mostly on this project for months and so I want sleep option workin in my pc

Comment: @user1 and thanks for the idea and I would try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the program entry point change the settings, restore settings at the end when debug session finishes.

Take this example....

```
#include <cstdlib>
//include windows.h

using namespace std;

void KeepMonitorActive() {
    // Enable away mode and prevent the sleep idle time-out.
    SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
}

void RestoreMonitorSettings() {
    // Clear EXECUTION_STATE flags to disable away mode and allow the system to idle to sleep normally.
    SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS);
}

int main()
{
    //Add these 2 lines at the entry point in your program
    KeepMonitorActive();
    atexit(RestoreMonitorSettings);

   //...
}
```

Comment: This is C++11 solution, but you would not have problem running this example since you are already using VS 2013. VS 2013 supports std::thread

Comment: In most cases it wouldn't be necessary to spawn a separate thread.  There is usually an existing thread (most commonly the main thread) that will be present for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: No, my answer is evolving :)

Comment: #include "windows.h" should be available. U have commented it.

Comment: My answer is for your reference. I don't know what program are you running. Win32 console, mfc ? Most likely Windows.h would be included in your project.

Comment: This worked. Thanks user1. But one last question.. Why can't we directly call SetThreadExecutionState() function at the beginning of main method and at the end of it, with relavant arguments. ? Why do we use extra function to call them? Is it a coding standard or is there any other use by the way that you have done it?

Comment: Surely, you can replace KeepMonitorActive() call with SetThreadExecutionState(). But not RestoreMonitorSettings(), the reason I used atexit() is because, It will ensure that it will restore the system settings back. If you don't use atexit(), you would then have to call SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS); in all places where function "returns" conditionally. from maintenance perspective, it is far easier to add these 2 lines at the main() entry than modify all conditional returns in your program.

Comment: Many Thanks @user1. I was hoping to accept the answer but missed seeing your comment and so was waiting more... Sorry for keeping u waiting until a acceptance request.

Answer (score 5):

There is [SetThreadExecutionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208(v=vs.85).aspx) function in windows